# Formatting the navbar on WordPress Elementor

Tags: wordpress, navbar, elementor

On the WordPress site, I am using the free version of Elementor, and I have to do the layout of the navbar.

I am also using the default theme. And I can only use the PRO version of Elementor.

Here is what I have so far: [nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAt48.png)

I would like it to be a normal horizontal navbar (I use the default wordpress theme), I watched the tutorials on youtube, tested Clever Mega Menu for Elementor, but it doesn't work.
And can't edit via custom CSS, as it's only available in the Pro version of Elementor. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below plugin,
it will allow you to create header and footer with elementor.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-footer-elementor/